# The instances where verbs might take the genitive case

Tags: grammar-choice, genitive, word-order

In Sixto-Clementine Vulgate we find in Genesis this verse:

> poenituit eum quod **hominum** fecisset in terra (Genesis 6:6)

"hominum" is in the genetive case which I find strange. I try searching for the instances where genetive case would be used after verb, and it seems to be related mainly to remember/forgetting verbs.

So I wonder if that's a general practice or I'm missing something in my analysis of the verse.

(by the way, other translations indeed use the accusative case (sometime in singular) in this verse).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hominum is a post-classical (or if you prefer: erroneous) spelling for hominem (acc. sing.).

Comment: Thanks. is that kind of a general tendency, or just for specific words?

Comment: Vegliot yomno seems to imply hominum.

Comment: I don't understand what "Vegliot yomno" stands for ?

Comment: @d_e. Vegliot was an extinct Romance language spoken on the island of Veglio in the Adriatic. The Vegliot word for "man" in "yomno", which seems to derive from Vulgar Latin "hominum", not "hominem".

Comment: @d_e To clarify a bit further: nouns in Romance languages are almost always derived from the accusative singular of the Latin nouns. We'd expect *yomno* to come from Vulgar Latin *hominum*, and something like \*_yomne_ from Vulgar Latin *hominem*; *yomno* is the one that we see, which implies that people were using *hominum* as the accusative.